# Pandas dataframe isn't getting updated when passed to a function that drops some rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a problem where I have in the same dataframe lines that are opposites.

```
       coldate col1 col2 col3
row_1  d1      1    2    3 
row_2  d2.     1    2    2
row_3  d1      1    2    -3
```

The condition fro opposite rows is : having the same value for col1 and col2 and (-1)*col3. In my example row_1 and row_3 are opposites.

My solution (I know it may not be the optimal one).

I created two identical dataframes : df and df2.

I have the following function that iterate over the first dataframe "df" and searches in the second dataframe "df2" opposites rows to drop.

```
 def delete_opposite_rows(df, row):
    mask = ((df['col1'] == row['col1']) & 
           (df['col2'] == row['col2']) & 
           (df['col3'] == (-1) * row['col3']))
    indexes = df.loc[mask].index 
    if len(indexes) > 0:
        if len(indexes) == 1:
            df.drop(indexes[0], inplace=True)
        else:
            # Search the row from "df" closest  in time to "row"
            df_row_to_drop = df.iloc[indexes] 
            # Create a copy cause the function iloc return a slice of the dataframe
            df_row_to_drop = df_row_to_drop(deep=True)
            # Compute the time interval between the "row" and the invoice lines
            df_row_to_drop['daysSinceCredit'] = df_row_to_drop['coldate'].apply(
                lambda x: (row['coldate'] - x).days)
              df_row_to_drop.drop(df_row_to_drop[df_row_to_drop['daysSinceCredit'] < 0].index,inplace=True)
            df.drop(df_row_to_drop['daysSinceCredit'].idxmin(), inplace=True)
            del df_row_to_drop
    del indexes
    del mask
```

I'm calling this function as follow :

```
df.apply(lambda row: delete_opposite_rows(df2, row), axis=1)
```

My error is that :
In the first iteration : the function founds and deletes row 541 from df2 that is opposite to the row 2 from df. In the new df2, every row is supposed to gain one index position.

In the second iteration : the function founds the row 547 from df2 that is opposite to row 5 of df. The problem here is that row 547 isn't the opposite row of 5. The opposite row is the row 546 of df2.

Which means that the code :

```
mask = ((df['col1'] == row['col1']) & 
           (df['col2'] == row['col2']) & 
           (df['col3'] == (-1) * row['col3']))
    indexes = df.loc[mask].index
```

searched in the original df2 not the one after the first iteration.

Do you have an idea why this is happening ? Does the loc[mask] keeps some cached data between two calls ?

I hope my problem is clear

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: In the second iteration, The row should have been 546 not 547. It's like the dataframe df2 wasn't updated after the first iteration when calling the df.loc[mask]